# iOS Parse Block results stored in a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, uitableview, block

I am using the Parse iOS SDK and I would like to store my findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`: query in a`UILabel`.  The`UILabel`is created inside of the`viewForHeaderInSection`: method of my table view.

If I create the `UILabel` inside of the block I can successfully store the value that I need and show the Label on my View.  When a query runs in Parse it tries to connect to the server 3 times before the query uses the local cache.  If any of the tries fail or if the connection to the server is slow my `UILabel` flickers.  I don't want that, so my thought is to somehow access the result of my query outside of the block and store it as the `UILabel` after the block completes.

Can someone show me how to access the result of my query outside of the block and store the result in a `UILabel`?

The example that I have below is how I am currently creating the `UILabel` on my view and displaying the result of my block as the `UILabel`.  Thanks for the help!

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
                UIView *myHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,320,20)];
                myHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

                PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
                query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
                [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if (!error) 
                {
                    NSNumber *sum = [objects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.sumResults"];
                    UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,120,20)] ;
                    myLabel1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
                    myLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sum results: %.1f", [sum floatValue]];
                    [myHeader addSubview:myLabel1];

                } 
                else 
                {
                     NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }

        }];

        return myHeader;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A big part of the problem is that you're creating your label within the "`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`" result (completion) block.  So it's not easily available to any other place in your app outside of that block of code.

What I'd recommend doing is having your UILabel as an IBOutlet (i.e. you put it into your storyboard or xib file and connect it to an outlet in your view controller).

Then, when you get results you want to display, [post a notification to yourself (or any observers) that it's time to update](https://parse.com/questions/ios-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-block-ui) (I'd recommend 
[`postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:) where the userInfo dictionary contains whatever info you want to add to that label).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your label in a block, making it unavailable for the rest of your code. 
In order to access the label from outside the block, create a property in your .m file:

```
@interface YourViewController()
//here comes your label
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel1;
@end
```

And then synthesize it after your @implementation:

```
@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize myLabel1;
```

Now, instead of calling

```
UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,120,20)];
```

simply call

```
myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,120,20)];
```

Then you can access your label from everywhere in your code (but make sure you initiated it already when trying to access it! In your case, when you stick with initiating it in your `viewForHeaderInSection` method, make sure you access it only after this method has been called and the label has effectively been initiated.